# Display json data to HTML file

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax

Just start practicing ajax using this fake api service. [JSONPlaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/)

But I'm confused with displaying data to html file. I just want to show data like this.

Blog title: unt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit (comes with jason file)

Blog post: "quia et suscipit suscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum reprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam nostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto" (comes with jason file)

It has provided root

```
var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

$.ajax({
  url: root + '/posts/1',
  method: 'GET'
}).then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

How can I display data to html?

Comment: instead of logging this data on the console...create a html element and make its content as this data and append it to the body

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing you have such json:

```
{
    title: 'My awesome title',
    description: 'My awesome description'
}
```

And such HTML code:

```
<h1 id="title"></h1>
<div id="description"></div>
```

You should do

```
$('#title').text(data.title);
$('#description').text(data.decription);
```

instead of

```
console.log(data);
```

Comment: @CssSY `$('#image').attr('src', data.imageUrl)`, where `image` is id of your `img` tag

Comment: Great. Is it possible to use crud actions using this api?

Comment: Yes. You may take a look at jQuery documentation. [This](https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/) could be a good start point.

Answer (score 1):

You can display the JSON data in your HTML using **Data Object Manipulation (DOM)** in JavaScript.

You can do it like this in jQuery:

```
<p>Hello World</p>


<script> 
    var root = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com";
    $.ajax({
      url: root + '/posts/1',
      method: 'GET'
    }).then(function(data) {
      $("p").html(data.title); 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You can update the src attribute of the img tag by using `$("img").attr("src", data.imageSource);`. This is just an example though, change it depending on your needs. But that should do the job

Answer (score 1):

```
Display json data into html with below from the json response,

  $("div").html('<div>'+data.title+'</div><div>'+data.description+'</div>');
```